# A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately on Socket.Receive

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

I have c# code that sends a file, and then waits for an ACK. This code works fine on most systems, but we have one client who is getting the error: `A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately.` I'm wondering if this could be caused by a firewall issue, and if there is anything that can be done in the code to resolve it. Below is the basic code used to receive the ACK, with processing cut out for brevity.

```
            using (Socket socket = ConnectSocket(server, port))
            {
                if (socket != null)
                {
                    socket.Send(bytesSent, bytesSent.Length, 0);
                    socket.ReceiveTimeout = ReceiveTimeout;
                    int bytes;

                    //  loop in case the ACK is longer than 256 bytes
                    int failedAttempts = 0;
                    do
                    {
                        bytes = 0;
                        try
                        {
                            bytes = socket.Receive(bytesReceived, bytesReceived.Length, 0);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            HandleException(e) // Mostly logging
                        }
                        ack.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesReceived, 0, bytes));

                        //  Break out after 1 minute of no reconnect.
                        if(failedAttempts > 60)
                            bytes = 0;
                    } while (bytes == bytesReceived.Length);
                }
            }
```

The error is happening when I call `bytes = socket.Receive(bytesReceived, bytesReceived.Length, 0);` Am I doing something wrong? I could set `Socket.Blocking = true`, but it seems this would just cause the code to freeze up. Again, this code works on all but one client's system, which makes me think firewall, but they have monitored firewall traffic, and say that it is not getting blocked.

Thanks.

Comment: Such an 'error' is as designed.

Comment: I see a lot of superstitiousness in your code. You are using APIs without understanding them. Sockets are a sharp tool that is easily misused. You need to be more meticulous.

Comment: That you only see an issue on one user’s system suggests that it is a timing issue. You’re actually lucky that your code works at all on other systems as this is how non-blocking sockets are supposed to work.

Answer (score 2):

In the MSDN Socket.ReceiveMethod documentation , you can read:

> If no data is available for reading, the Receive method will block
>   until data is available, unless a time-out value was set by using
>   Socket.ReceiveTimeout. If the time-out value was exceeded, the Receive
>   call will throw a SocketException. If you are in non-blocking mode,
>   and there is no data available in the in the protocol stack buffer,
>   the Receive method will complete immediately and throw a
>   SocketException. You can **use the Available property to determine if
>   data is available for reading**. When Available is non-zero, retry the
>   receive operation.